# Error in trigger function in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have three tables in my database - `Students`, `Books` and `Books2student`.

- `Students` table has `StudentID, First_Name, Last_Name`.
- `Books` table has `ISBN_no, name, no. of copies available`.
- `Books2Students` table which has `StudentID, books issued, issue date, due date`.

I want to create a trigger that when a student is deleted from `books2students` then `no. of copies` in `Books` table should be increased and if I insert a book in `books2student` then `no of copies` in books should be decreased.

I wrote a function  and trigger,  but I am getting error in the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION student_to_book()   RETURNS trigger AS  '
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = ''DELETE'' THEN
        UPDATE books 
        SET books.no_of_copies_available = no_of_copies_available+1
        WHERE Books2Students.Book_Issued=books.ISBN_no;

  END IF;
  IF tg_op = ''INSERT'' THEN
        UPDATE books  
        SET books.no_of_copies_available = no_of_copies_available-1
        WHERE Books2Students.Book_Issued=books.ISBN_no;   

  END IF;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get error an error:

> ```
> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "books2students"
>   Where: PL/pgSQL function student_to_book() line 10 at SQL statement
> ```

Comment: To refer to the row that is being inserted or deleted (for which the trigger has been fired), the syntax is `NEW.book_issued` or `OLD.book_issued` instead of `Books2Students.Book_Issued`. That's the reason of the error. See postgres documentation for more.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues. This could work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION student_to_book()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      UPDATE books 
      SET    no_of_copies_available = no_of_copies_available + 1
      WHERE  ISBN_no = OLD.Book_Issued;

   ELSIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
      UPDATE books  
      SET    no_of_copies_available = no_of_copies_available - 1
      WHERE  ISBN_no = NEW.Book_Issued;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

- [The manual about the special records `OLD` and `NEW`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)
- [The manual about `UPDATE`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

That does not cover `TG_OP = UPDATE`, yet ...

Often, a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) is a better approach to keep track of a count per book.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are referring to the table books2students in the `WHERE` clause but not having a `FROM` clause for it. I assume the trigger is for this table so you can use the keyword `NEW` in the update part and the keyword `OLD` in the delete part instead of the table name. Like this:

```
IF tg_op = ''INSERT'' THEN
UPDATE books
  SET books.no_of_copies_available = no_of_copies_available-1
  WHERE NEW.Book_Issued=books.ISBN_no;
```