# Create a trigger on a table that fires on UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT

Tags: postgresql, triggers

In Postgres, do you have to create a new trigger for each event, or is there a way to combine them and have the trigger fire whenever data is inserted, deleted or updated on a table?

Comment: Yes. See *Example 43.4. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Function for Auditing* here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). Also statement diagram here [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: One trigger and one trigger function could be enough to handle all you events. But it depends on your requirements, there is for example a difference between a BEFORE and AFTER. If you need them both, you need two triggers and at least one trigger function.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, no you don't. You can have one trigger that covers  multiple actions.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I don't fully agree because some data is just not available. And Yes, these are exceptions, but they do occur and this is also why there is a difference between the two.

Comment: Alright I skipped over the BEFORE/AFTER situation. In that case there needs to be a trigger for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The syntax is like:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION my_trigger_func();
```

Before Postgres 11 the (misleading) keyword was `PROCEDURE` instead of `FUNCTION`, which is still accepted in Postgres 15 (and probably for much longer).

There are many syntax variants. Details in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Related:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307500/3684)
- [FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193567/for-each-statement-trigger-example/24195624#24195624)
- [Can a function detect the trigger event type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743766/can-a-function-detect-the-trigger-event-type/23744320#23744320)
- [Error in trigger function in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152157/error-in-trigger-function-in-postgresql/29177726#29177726)

Comment: so inside of my function, how do I know if it was an update, delete or insert?  It is a AFTER trigger, and my function currently references `NEW.product_id`.

Comment: @Blankman: See TG_OP Please read the manual, all information is there, including examples: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: @Blankman: Follow the [provided link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23744320/939860) to my answer that addresses this question exactly. And read the manual. Note that `NEW` is not defined in case of a `DELETE`.

Comment: If NEW exists, but the column is null, can I safely do a `NEW.product_id IS NOT NULL` check?

Comment: Yes, `NEW` is a record variable. If assigned, you can do that. Except for (rare) [statement level triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24195624/939860). My previous comment was not precise. Since Postgres 10, when not applicable, `NEW` & `OLD` are NULL rather than unassigned. Either way, switch cases based on `TG_OP` in the trigger function or write separate functions and triggers. Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566232/939860).